# Is instagram public Api stopped working? (__a=1&__d=dis method)

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-reels

[https://www.instagram.com/reel/CtJsfErrMJ3/?__a=1&__d=dis](https://stackoverflow.com)

Is this Api stopped working?

```
{"message":"Please wait a few minutes before you try again.","require_login":true,"status":"fail"}
```

Getting this error response when hitting this Api.

Is there any method to get reels data without using cookie?

I wanted any other solution that gives data of instagram reels and post.

Comment: It's impossible for us to know, that's something you should ask to Instagram support. Based on the given message, it seems like a temporary outage or some kind of rate-limiting thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=<query hash>&variables={"shortcode":"<short code>"}
```

This is working without login or cookies

Example:

```
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=b3055c01b4b222b8a47dc12b090e4e64&variables={"shortcode":"CtO-WItvI4d"}
```

Comment: Can elaborate <query hash> and <short code> if i want to extract data from reel. https://www.instagram.com/reel/CtJNSSsgrS9/?igshid=MzRlODBiNWFlZA==

Comment: Also give one example url with all parameters.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @VinitHingu I had updated my answer by including example.

Comment: @BadTrickerters8484 can you give API URL that is used to get Instagram story data?

Comment: @VinitHingu There is no change in downloading the story. Only the logged in user can download it.

Comment: Where do you get the query_hash value? I assume the shortcode is the ID for the media itself, but what is query_hash?

Comment: @BadTrickerters8484 do you have this kind of public API for facebook video?

Comment: @BadTrickerters8484 how do you get <query hash> ?